# Pass a variable from the DOM to SCSS

Tags: angular, sass

I am using angular with .scss and I would like to know how to do the below .less code in .scss instead.

HTML

```
<span class="flag-icon-{{territoryId}}"></span>
```

CSS

```
.flag-icon-@{country} {
  //@country being the {{territoryId}} from above
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Sayooj V R**: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10647431/sayooj-v-r

I tried your above, but it didn't seem to work, but it gave me more knowledge of what I can do with `scss` and I managed to figure it out (woohoo!) with the below code:

HTML

```
<span class="flag-icon-{{territoryId}}"></span>
```

SCSS

```
$country-collection: ('india', 'usa', 'germany', 'pakistan');

@each $country in $country-collection {
    .flag-icon-#{$country} {
      color: red
    }
}
```

The @for didn't seem to be working for some reason (not sure why) so I tried a different loop technique using the `@each` method, and walaaaah it worked!

The documentation for `@each` is here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<span class="flag-icon-{{territoryId}}"></span>
```

scss file

```
$country-collection: ('india', 'usa', 'germany', 'pakistan');

@for $country from 0 to length($country-collection) {
    .flag-icon-#{$country} {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't quite work! But I managed to figure it out and it worked with the below code! Thank you so much!